# "TypeError: minimatch is not a function" error when running new expo project

Tags: node.js, expo, npx

I have the following libraries installed on my M1 Macbook running Ventura 13.3.1:

```
$ nvm -v
0.39.3
$ node -v
v18.16.0
$ npm -v
9.6.4
$ npx expo -v
0.7.0
```

I generated a new expo project using the command:

```
npx create-expo-app my-app --template
```

I choose the blank Typescript template. It generated an app and then I cd into the app directory. When I run `npx run web`, first it asks for me to install some dependencies, so then I do:

```
npx expo install react-native-web@~0.18.10 react-dom@18.2.0 @expo/webpack-config@^18.0.1
```

Now when I try to run `npx run web`, I get the following error:

```
/Users/paul/.npm/_npx/755986f37193a6d8/node_modules/run/run.js:127
    if (minimatch(file, pattern)) {
        ^

TypeError: minimatch is not a function
```

How get I fix this error and get the expo server to start?

Comment: I am also seeing this today on all of my node run projects.

Comment: I think adding `run` to the dependency list will fix this as `minimatch` is a dependency of `run`

Comment: The issue seems to have gone away for me after I deleted the project, upgraded nvm, node and npm all to their latest versions and then generated a new project

Answer (score 32):

I was getting this when trying to run an Astro project:

```
npx run dev
```

The problem was that I was actually supposed to be running `npm run`:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: subtle but very dangerous mistake  i just made it today

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to minimatch **v9**, in order to fix this just change

```
minimatch()
```

to

```
minimatch.minimatch()
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason for the error message was that I was running `npx run my-package` instead of `npx my-package`... d'oh!

Answer (score -3):

The **minimatch** is used internally by npm, and this error occurs due to a problem installing the dependencies.
To fix it, just delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Now everything should work perfectly!

Comment: This does not resolve the issue